# Writing to xml file with PHP domXML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create a xml file and save it using domXML. However when it creates the xml file it does not create a parent node. This is how the xml file writes now.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed>
 <headline></headline>
 <author></author>
 <link></link>    
 <image></image>
 <description></description>
</feed>
```

I need the xml file to look like this when it it is created and need to be able to insert more items into `<feeds>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feeds>
 <feed>
  <headline></headline>
  <author></author>
  <link></link>    
  <image></image>
  <description></description>
 </feed>
</feeds>
```

Here is the script I am using. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

```
$mainheadline = $_POST['headline'];
$mainauthor = $_POST['author'];
$mainlink = $_POST['link'];
$mainimage = $_POST['image'];
$maindescription = $_POST['description'];

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->load("newsfeed/newsfeed.xml");

$root = $doc->createElement('feeds');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$xml = $doc->createElement('feed');
$xml = $root->appendChild($xml);

$headline = $doc->createElement('headline', $mainheadline);
$headline = $xml->appendChild($headline);

$author = $doc->createElement('author', $mainauthor);
$author = $xml->appendChild($author);

$link = $doc->createElement('link', $mainlink);
$link = $xml->appendChild($link);

$image = $doc->createElement('image', $mainimage);
$image = $xml->appendChild($image);

$description = $doc->createElement('description', $maindescription);
$description = $xml->appendChild($description);

$doc->save("newsfeed/newsfeed.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append to an existing XML file, simply locate the root node and add children from there. The only challenge is to build the first file versus all the rest. Below uses a conditional `if` logic to decide depending if `newsfeed.xml` file exists or not.

Below includes lines needed for very first xml and all xml files thereafter.

```
$mainheadline = $_POST['headline'];
$mainauthor = $_POST['author'];
$mainlink = $_POST['link'];
$mainimage = $_POST['image'];
$maindescription = $_POST['description'];

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Condition first xml versus appended xml files
if (!file_exists("newsfeed/newsfeed.xml")) {
    $root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElement('feeds'));
}
else {
    $doc->load("newsfeed/newsfeed.xml");  
    $root = $doc->documentElement;  
}

$xml = $root->appendChild($doc->createElement('feed'));

$xml->appendChild($doc->createElement('headline', $mainheadline));
$xml->appendChild($doc->createElement('author', $mainauthor));
$xml->appendChild($doc->createElement('link', $mainlink));
$xml->appendChild($doc->createElement('image', $mainimage));
$xml->appendChild($doc->createElement('description', $maindescription));

// Save file
$doc->save("newsfeed/newsfeed.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated my code above and I get the correct format however,  every time the html form is submitted it now writes the `feeds` tag before each item. I just need each "feed" to be in between one set of "feeds" tag. I edited original post above so you can see what I did.

Comment: What do you mean before each item? What item? `feeds` would be the root node at beginning and end of document. Actually, now that I see it closely, you are not creating a document from scratch but loading another xml.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that poorly. Basically want I want to happen is that another  `feed` is added when the user submits the html form. Right now if I submit the form it creates the `feeds` tag for each submission.